# How can I give a key that's null to the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I fix this??

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

This is the error message :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acu1g.png

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        string url = "http://linsa.softinsa.com/account/login";
        HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);

        var head = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
        var meta = head.SelectNodes("//meta").AsEnumerable();
        var link = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head").SelectNodes("//link").AsEnumerable();

        var titulo = "" ;
        var descricao = "" ;
        var linkImg = "" ;
        var linkIcon = "" ;

        Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
        string host = myUri.Host;


        var fbProperties = (head.SelectNodes("//meta[contains(@property, 'og:')]") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
            .ToDictionary(n => n.Attributes["property"].Value, n => n.Attributes["content"].Value);

        linkIcon = (head.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@rel, 'apple-touch-icon')]")?.Attributes["href"]?.Value) ??
            (head.SelectSingleNode("//link[conntains((@rel, 'icon']")?.Attributes["href"]?.Value) ??
            host + "/favicon.ico";


        var title = head.SelectSingleNode("//title")?.InnerText;



        titulo = fbProperties["og:title"] ?? title ?? "";

        descricao = fbProperties["og:description"];

        linkImg = fbProperties["og:image"];


        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Titulo:");
        Console.WriteLine(titulo);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Descriçao:");
        Console.WriteLine(descricao);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Link da Imagem:");
        Console.WriteLine(linkImg);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Link do Icon:");
        Console.WriteLine(linkIcon);

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not know that it was there, you should use

[ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx): `if (fbProperties.ContainsKey("og:title")) { ... }`

or

[TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639.aspx): `fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:title", out value);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) to check that the key exists in the dictionary before trying to get it out using the index operator.

For example:

```
titulo = fbProperties["og:title"] ?? title ?? "";
```

Becomes:

```
if(fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:title", out titulo) == false || titulo == null)
{
  titulo = (title ?? "");
}
```

And:

```
escricao = fbProperties["og:description"];
```

Becomes

```
fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:description", out descricao);
```

As `TryGetValue` will set `descricao` to `null` if it cannot find they key.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure if a given entry exists within a dictionary then you should use the [`TryGetValue()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method returns `true` or `false` to indicate if the given key was found, and has an `out` parameter used to return the value when found. (Note that the `out` parameter is set to its default value when the key was not found in the dictionary)

See the following example where I've adapted the getting of the "title" to use the `TryGetValue()` method:

```
if (fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:title", out titulo) == false)
{
    // Fall-back to "title" or an empty string when not found in dictionary
    titulo = title ?? "";
}
```